# Translating complex logic to MySQL CASE statement

Tags: mysql, join, logic, case

I'm having translating the following logic into a MySQL CASE statement, I'm sure there is an elegant way to do it but I think I have been working on for way too long and confused my self!

The business rules:

- Programmes have an programme_start and programme_end
- Individuals have an attend_start and attend_end

Individuals attend multiple programmes during one period, they can only have one of the following example attendance spans:

[image]

What I need to do is categorise each span into a category type i.e. Type 1 ... 9. but I'm having trouble building up a CASE statement that can mutually exclusively cover each span.

Has anyone done something like this before? If not could someone help with the logic behind it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cases are quite simple..

In the case of a single time, there are only 3 ways a time can be classified - before, on and after.  There are two times involved, so 3 x 3 = 9 results.

There is something to be said about consistency though, because for _start, it goes:

```
on - after - before
```

Whereas for the _end time, it goes

```
on - before - after
```

Combine them using (assuming no consideration for NULLs):

```
case when programme_start = attend_start then 0
     when programme_start < attend_start then 3
     else 6 end
+
case when programme_end = attend_end then 1
     when programme_end > attend_end then 2
     else 3 end
AS Category
```

Comment: neat trick with adding the cases together! Haven't decided if I think it is Hack or Heaven... but you get my vote :)